# Android Parse Push

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push

I'm using Parse services to send push messages to devices. 
On iOS everything works well but on Android if I send a push message it shows my package name ("com.example.app") to the receiver. Why isn't it showing my app's name ("Example App")? 
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Is it because it's in debug mode not release?

Comment: show your push receiver code if custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check again your source code, I follow Parse Document and it works properly, You maybe send wrong content of the title

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ZHSplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```